# Class Threading Consistency

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, executorservice

As part of a project I am currently working on we (a few fellow coding enthusiasts friends) we are trying to make a relatively simple game. The game was to consist of several smaller games that we would program separately and my job was to combine them together into a sorta frankensteined super game. 
One of these mini games consists of a "transportation Simulator". Very similar to something like frogger; just a lane swerving minigame. My friend who programmed this has it running 14 swing workers to complete tasks like spawning oncoming cars, road animations and your car. The problem I am having is when I call this class all of the threads don't launch. Some don't activate till after others finish, and others will run behind others. I moved the swingworkers into an Execution Service, but still get similar results. Is there a cap on number of threads running simultaneously? Are swingworkers the wrong thing for the job? It is very confusing for me because I cannot see any consistency in the failed threads. There seems to be no reason why sometimes they launch and other times don't. Any suggestions? 
This is the Constructor

```
      travelGUI(Player playerIn) throws InterruptedException {

  ...

    //player is a object that contains a variable for each GUI
    //it is also a Parameter
    player = playerIn;

    player.mapGUI.setVisible(false);
    player.mapGUI.dispose();

    methodNewThread();//road display
    carThread();//Used to update the car in the game
    copShootThread();
    copShootThread();//Used to set up the bullet shoot thread that shoots at the car

    healthThread();
    bulletThread();
    copThread("1", 1, "1" + "p");
    copThread("2", 2, "2" + "p");
    copThread("3", 3, "3" + "p");
    copThread("4", 4, "4" + "p");

    //Creates the background animation for the road and the end conditions for the level
    intComponents();
}
```

an example of one of the threads is
          public static void healthThread() {//This thread is used to update the players health

```
    SwingWorker<Void, String> he;
    he = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            //code to be run in the new thread
            ...
            }
            return null;
        }

    };

    // he.execute();
    executorService.submit(he);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the cap on concurrent threads is the number of CPU cores you have.  Two for many folks still, four in some more expensive systems.

Comment: So a fair solution without rewriting nearly the whole class is to try and combine as many threads together as posible?

Comment: *"My friend who programmed this has it running 14 swing workers"* - That's interesting, because `SwingWorker` is rate limited to 10

Comment: *"I moved the swingworkers into an Execution Service"* - Okay, `SwingWorker` schedules it's workers on it's own, private, `ExecutorService`, which is limited to 10 active threads - which probably points straight down to your key problem - the real question is, "Why in hell do you need so many workers"?  In reality, a single thread is more than enough to accomplish the job at hand

Comment: Thank you for asking that bluntly! Im currently working to get rid of all of the threads. Looking at this class i think every method is a new class. I think this explains the weird behavior and randomness to the programme. Basically depending on CPU usage and core availability it would execute differently.